# Gridviewscroll does not work on too many records

Tags: javascript, fixed-header-tables

I used this gridview scroll, [github](https://github.com/twlikol/GridViewScroll) . It works well in most tables. However, if table has too many frozen cells, they disappear one by one. [image: col disappeared after "Kaba İşleme"]

Javascript file: http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Scripts/gridviewScroll.min.js?20130319

Anyone else got that problem? How can i solve it?

If there is another "stable" fixed header-column script, please tell me.